# Convertir/decodificar caracter en pagina html y convertirla en una lista

Tags: html, python, lista

Tengo un servidor en python 'simpleHTTP' corriendo en mi maquina. El funciona como deberia pero existe un problema con el lado del cliente.

Se eleva un error cuando se intenta leer un directorio que tenga un acento en su nombre.

Esto me ha pasado ahora por que siempre he usado el idioma ingles en mis maquinas... Debido a que hice una nueva instalacion basada en Arch Linux y esta corrigio el idioma basaddo en la zona horaria este es el error que surgio ahora.

Un folder normal en ingles seria: Videos

Pero ya en el idioma español/latino seria: Vídeos

Este es un ejemplo de lo que recibe el cliente con:

`WebServerResponse = urllib.urlopen(Url).read()`

Salida:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><html>
<body>
<h2>Directory listing for /home/user/</h2>
<hr>
<ul>
<li><a href="Descargas/">Descargas/</a>
<li><a href="Documentos/">Documentos/</a>
<li><a href="Escritorio/">Escritorio/</a>
<li><a href="Im%C3%A1genes/">Imágenes/</a>
<li><a href="Matrix.txt">Matrix.txt</a>
<li><a href="M%C3%BAsica/">Música/</a>
<li><a href="Plantillas/">Plantillas/</a>
<li><a href="P%C3%BAblico/">Público/</a>
<li><a href="V%C3%ADdeos/">Vídeos/</a>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
```

Como ven para el folder: **Vídeos** este tiene como valor **V%C3%ADdeos**

Al ejecutar **URLReturn = urllib.urlopen(RemoteDevice).read()** y luego al ejecutar la funcion **urllib.unquote(URLReturn)** este logra darle el valor correcto a cada caracter... El problema es que si deseo partir el resultado en pedazos con el metodo **split('\n')** esta vuelve a codificarse pero esta vez remplaza las caracteres por otros.

Por ejemplo:

```
'href="V\xc3\xaddeos/">V\xc3\xaddeos/</a>'
```

Locale: es_PR.UTF-8

Que debo hacer para cambiar este comportamiento?

Edit: Este es la parte del servidor

```
def HTTPServerStart(Secure=False):

   # Generate Certificate
   # sudo openssl req -new -x509 -keyout /etc/ssl/certs/LocalHTTPSSever.pem -out /etc/ssl/certs/LocalHTTPSSever.pem -days 365 -nodes
   # https://letsencrypt.org/

   if Secure:         
      import BaseHTTPServer, ssl
      ServerType="HTTPS"
      print "Local Secure HTTP Server Enabled"
      print "You May Need To Add A Certificate Exception In Your Browser To Access The Server" 
   else:
      import SocketServer 
      ServerType="HTTP"

      import SimpleHTTPServer, os

   Port = 8000

   if not Secure:
      Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
      Handler.extensions_map.update({'.webapp': 'application/x-web-app-manifest+json',});

   ServerPath = os.environ['HOME']
   os.chdir(ServerPath)

   try:
      if Secure:
         try:
            httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", Port), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
            httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, certfile='/etc/ssl/certs/LocalHTTPSSever.pem', server_side=True)
         except ssl.SSLError:
            print "Error With SSL Certificate. Maybe You Will Need To Generate Another One" 
      else:
         httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", Port), Handler)
   except socket.error:
      print "%s Server Already Running On Selected Port %s" % (ServerType, Port)
      return False 

   print "Serving %s Server On Address %s://%s:%s/" % (ServerType, ServerType.lower(), Address()['NetworkIP'], Port)

   try:
      httpd.serve_forever()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      return "Exit"
```

Edit 2: Informacion de sistema

`uname -a`

> Linux Usuario 4.10.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 31 16:50:19 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`cat /etc/arch-release`

> Antergos Linux release 17.4 (ISO-Rolling)

`cat /etc/os-release`

> NAME="Antergos Linux"
>   VERSION="17.4-ISO-Rolling"
>   ID="antergos"
>   ID_LIKE="arch"
>   PRETTY_NAME="Antergos Linux"

`env`

> LC_COLLATE=es_PR.UTF-8
>   LANG=es_PR.UTF-8
>   GDMSESSION=xfce
>   TERM=xterm-256color
>   SHELL=/bin/bash

[**Sistema Operativo: Antergos**](https://antergos.com/try-it/)

Este sistema operativo fue instalado y se especifico a **Puerto Rico** como pais asi como zona horaria.

El ambiente de escritorio lo es: XFCE

Edit 3:

**Cliente HTTP**

```
import urllib 
WebServerResponse = urllib.urlopen(RemoteFile).read()
```

Hasta aquí todo marcha mas o menos bien. Esta es la salida del html que mostre mas arriba.

Entonces si utilizo `WebServer.split()` entonce se traduce a `'href="V%C3%ADdeos/">V\xc3\xaddeos/</a>'`

Pero si ejecuto `urllib.unquote(WebServerResponse).split()` entonces se genera la salida `'href="V\xc3\xaddeos/">V\xc3\xaddeos/</a>'`

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código con el que generas esa lista de directorios?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Ya anadi el codigo. Cabe destacar que si entro desde firefox y veo la fuente del html enviado por el servidor este sigue siendo el mismo. Para mi entender el problema no es con el servidor ni cliente... Seria basicamente como se interpreta la informacion por lo cual el enconding juega una parte crucial en esto.

Comment: Por lo que veo usas Python 2.x en ambos lados, servidor y cliente. Como comentas seguramente sea problema de encoding. En cuanto pueda simulo el código a ver si descubro algo... Saludos.

Comment: Saludo!! Bueno si es cierto que estoy usando **python 2.7** Dare mas informacion de sistema para replicar el ambiente exacto..  Verifica el nuevo edit y muchas gracias por la colaboracion!!

Comment: Si accedes a la url con firefox (http://ip_local:8000) si se muestrran los nombres de los directorios correctamente, al menos en mi caso es así. Tu problema es con la fución `split` solamente ¿no?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no es lo mismo imprimir la lista generada por `split` directamente `print lista`  que imprimir su contenido iterando sobre ella `print lista[0]`. ¿Si imprimes el contenido de la lista iterando sobre ella `for line in lista: print line` obtienes errores de codificación o no?

Comment: El problema si es con el metodo `split`. La respuesta obtenida por `urllib.urlopen(url).read()` obtiene el resultado igual que firefox osea que recibe por ejemplo `<li><a href="V%C3%ADdeos/">Vídeos/</a>`. El problema viene cuando se utiliza `split` y que termina conviertiendo los caracteres en otros como por ejemplo `'href="V%C3%ADdeos/">V\xc3\xaddeos/</a>'`

Comment: ¿El `split` lo haces sobre la salida de  `urllib.unquote(URLReturn)` verdad? Deberias añadir el código que usas para hacer la peticion al completo, tal y como lo usas. Desde `urllib.urlopen` hasta que imprimes la salida de `split`. Yo personalmente no puedo reproducir tu error, algo hacemos diferente.

Comment: Ya edite mi pregunta con el codigo basico hasta donde trabaja. Debe ser el encoding pero es que no encuentro la manera de dar el valor a los caracteres.. Aun utilizando `encode('latin1')` o `decode('utf8')` intercambiandolos y uniendolos `encode().decode()`

Comment: Repito porque no me contestaste a esto : ¿Como imprimes la lista, repito que no es lo mismo hacer `print urllib.unquote(WebServerResponse).split()` que usa el método __repr__ que imprimir cada elemento de la lista. ¿Si haces `for line in urllib.unquote(WebServerResponse).split('\n'): print line` que obtienes?

Comment: Obtengo: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1408: ordinal not in range(128)`

Pero si utiizo `Response = urllib.unquote(WebServerResponse).split()` y ejecuto `print Response[int]` entonces obtengo `href="Vídeos/">Vídeos/</a>`... Si ejecuto `net[85]` sin utilizar print entonces obtengo `'href="V\xc3\xaddeos/">V\xc3\xaddeos/</a>'`

Comment: El problema es que luego tendre que codificar todo para que salga otra vez de esta manera `V%C3%ADdeos` para poder accesar al proximo directorio... `Url = 'http://192.168.0.1:24000/home/user/V%C3%ADdeos/'` sino sale un error sobre el caracter `UnicodeError: contiene caracteres Non-ASCII`

Comment: Bueno al parecer tengo que utilizar en el proximo directorio `SaveDir = urllib.quote(Response[int])` Bastante ineficiente pero bueno que remedio... Si tienes alguna sugerencia para acelerar esto lo agradeceria. De todas formas muchas gracias por tu ayuda @FJSevilla